# Gatsby rendering and context issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I keep getting an empty pageContext object when hydration triggers the react page.
I have a page called [operatorSlug]/[tourSlug].tsx in the pages folder.

in the onCreatePage function in gatsby-node i have this:

```
if(page.path.match(/^\/\[operatorSlug\]\/\[tourSlug\]/)) {
        const tours = await getTours()
        for(const tour of tours) {
            const pagePath = '/${tour.operator.slug}/${tour.slug}'
            createPage({
                path: pagePath,
                matchPath: "/site/tours/:id",
                component: path.resolve("src/templates/[operatorSlug]/[tourSlug].tsx"),
                context: tour,
            })
        }
}
```

When the browser loads the html, i can see  that the contents of the contextObject were passed through and the generation step went well. Html looks good and renders all fields it is supposed to.
The issue is that as soon as js takes over, since the page doesnt receive the pageContext, the page turns out blank.

Any idea on what am i doing wrong?
How do i get the context to persist and load as a page prop in my page component?

I tried moving the page from pages to templates, i tried json stringifying the context object.. im out of ideas